# Download Azure DevOps work item attachments using node js and azure-devops-node-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-devops-rest-api

Got stuck while trying to download an attachment of a work item (Azure DevOps).

I'm Using node.js 'azure-devops-node-api' client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-node-api) to interact with ADO API. I get a certain workItem using WorkItemTracking client (wit):

`let workItem = await witApi.getWorkItem(1234, undefined, undefined, WorkItemExpand.All);`

`let attachment = await witApi.getAttachmentContent(attachmentId, fileName, projectId, true);`

Documentation states that getAttachmentContent method downloads an attachment (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/ff820b2dd0c9a09cf09e64e94d3f95818a77249d/api/WorkItemTrackingApi.ts#L392), as a return value I'm getting a ReadableStream which i tried to write to a file using standard fs module:

`fs.writeFile('WordDoc.docx', attachment, function (err) {if (err) return console.log(err);});`

File is created but is empty. While debugging i also see that attachment variable has type ReadableStream but inside has lot's of properties and values, among them there is a buffer which i actually would like to extract and pass to fs.writeFile but can't reach them

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should write using `WritableStream`. As the `getAttachmentContent` is returning a `ReadableStream`. Below is the pseudo code. It might work

```
let readableStream = await witApi.getAttachmentContent(attachmentId, fileName, projectId, true);
let writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('./WordDoc.docx');
readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
```